# .DS_Store still appears in git status despite being in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

```
$ cat .gitignore 

# OSX
*/.DS_Store
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

$ git status
On branch develop
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Assets/Sprites/.DS_Store

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

There are more unrelated files in .gitignore and status message right now, but .gitignore itself is not modified, this version is committed.

How can I fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git diff doesn't ignore specified files in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820056/git-diff-doesnt-ignore-specified-files-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure `.DS_Store` isn't in the cache:

```
git rm --cached -- Assets/Sprites/.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 17):

> `.DS_Store` still appears in `git status` despite being in `.gitignore`

That `.DS_Store` file is listed as a modified file in the output of `git status`, which means it's currently being tracked by Git. However, Git won't ignore a file that is currently being tracked, whether it be listed in your `.gitignore` file or not.

How did you get yourself in that situation? You must have inadvertently started tracking that `.DS_Store` file *before* adding the `.DS_Store` entry in your `.gitignore`.

> `.gitignore` itself is not modified, this version is committed.

The list of files to ignore is not determined by any version of the `.gitignore` file that you may have committed, as you seem to believe.
Instead, at any given time, Git uses the `.gitignore` file that's in your working tree (if any).

> How can I fix that?

You need to tell Git to stop tracking that `.DS_Store` file, by running

```
git rm --cached -- <path_to_the_.DS_Store-file>
```

Because of the `--cached` flag, the problematic `.DS_Store` file won't be removed from your working tree, but it will *not* be included in your subsequent commits, and it should be properly ignored from then on.

Comment: I did it without the `--`, and instead just the filepath

`git rm --cached ./DS_Store` and it still worked.

What does the `--` do?

Comment: @ahnbizcad See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750028/in-git-what-does-dash-dash-mean?lq=1

Comment: '--' ensures things go smoothly... (E.g. if your file name starts with a '-' character)