# GIT and ignore existing data

Tags: git, tfs, ignore

I have a git repository on my NAS. I use from Windows and Linux SmartGit/Hg for interface with it.
I had to took some old repository make in TFS and convert into GIT one, so far so good (difficult procedure but I had success). For the new project I can tell GIT (before the first "commit") which directory I want to exclude, however the converted repository automatically put in git some directory that heritace from TFS. I suppose that TFS also had all the change of this directory.

So I thought that I can tell to GIT to ignore this directory but from SmartGit/Hg seems that if a directory/file is committed once I can't put it into ignore directory, so how can I tell to git to ignore for the future that directory?

Comment: This is basically a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820056/git-diff-doesnt-ignore-specified-files-in-gitignore)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove that folder from your index (but not from your disk):

```
git rm --cached -r yourFolder
```

(See "[`gitignore` after commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6535362/6309)" and "[How to remove a directory in my GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313301/6309)")

Then the `.gitignore` will be able to ignore the folder.

```
yourFolder/
```

Comment: Fantastic, it's everything that I need! Thanks VoC

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gitignore file. 
Here you can define which directories and files will not commited.

Click on the link below:
https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Kevin