# How to ignore some specific files and folders during Git diff and merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, gitignore, git-bash

I have 2 branches in SFDX enabled project. mybranch and develop. I want to merge selected changes from develop and then merge those in mybranch. 
As a starting point I am trying to use git diff to see what all is extra in develop, however, it is mentioning files like .forceignore, .gitignore and all. And I want to compare only force-app folder. Is there any way I could make git diff & git merge to ignore a set of files & folder as .gitignore is not working. FYI, I have already gone through following and it doesn't help me - [Git diff doesn't ignore specified files in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820056/git-diff-doesnt-ignore-specified-files-in-gitignore)

Appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Well .gitignore is used to ignore files you don't wanna push to the origin.

Don't git add the files u don't wanna push.

try git checkout -- filename for discarding the changes in files u have made.

Comment: Hello Sagar, So as you are suggesting, .gitignore doesn't play a role in git diff or git merge ?

Comment: This answer misses a lot of key aspects of `.gitignore`, but, @VarunSFDC, yes, `.gitignore` won't help with either diff or merge here. The `.gitignore` is not really about *ignoring* files at all (and hence is misnamed) but a correct name would be horribly long: dot-Git-here-are-files-that-if-they-are-untracked-right-now-don't-complain-about-them-and-don't-auto-add-them-with-en-masse-add-operations, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to compare differences/ changes for specific folder or file please try the command bellow:**

```
git diff your_branch1:path/to/folder your_branch2:path/to/folder
```

**If you already have difftool configured, then you can also use:** `git difftool your_branch1:path/to/folder your_branch2:path/to/folder`

For more you can explore [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

**Since [git 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths/21079437#21079437) something you can do exclude a specific file or folder**

```
git diff branch_name  -- . ':(exclude)file_path_to_ignore_1' ':(exclude)file_path_to_ignore_2'
```

Note: For windows syntax use  `git diff branch_name  -- . ":(exclude)file_path_to_ignore_1"` (double quotes instead of single quotes)

Comment: Hello Naib, Thanks for your feedback. However, the thing is, Support, I want to compare a folder say, force-app which further has 3 folders - force-app/dir1, force-app/dir2 & force-app/dir3... However I want to skip comparison of force-app/dir2 as want to keep it intact. Hence, I was thinking about .gitignore

Also, adding to it, eventually I would like to merge selected changes based on the o/p of git diff (if .gitignore helps me)... Do you recommend any guidelines I can follow for my scenario ?

Comment: If you compare for a folder, it will definitely do  comparison for all the sub-folder/child-folder of parent folder.
Please try atleast

Comment: Hello Naib, I will surely try... But my point is if there is a way to skip comparison of any subfolder.

Comment: yes you can do this. please see edited answer :) its something like git diff branch_name  -- . ':(exclude).gitignore'